# Multithreading C++ longer execution than single thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm trying to write a piece of code, which goes over a loop of 8^12 iterations, and in each iteration when some conditions are met I push_back to a vector (each thread has its own vector to push_back, which I combine after the loop). But it seems that my the execution is more time consuming the more threads are active. Here' the function (method of an object) passed to each thread:

```
void HamiltonianKH::mapping_kernel(ull_int start, ull_int stop, std::vector<ull_int>* map_threaded, int _id) {
int n = 1;
out << "A new thread joined tha party! from " << start << " to " << stop << endl;
for (ull_int j = start; j < stop; j++) {
    int bSz = 0, fSz = 0, N_e = 0;
    std::tie(bSz, fSz, N_e) = calculateSpinElements(this->L, j);
    if ((bSz + fSz == this->Sz) && N_e == this->num_of_electrons) 
         map_threaded->push_back(j);
    if (show_system_size_parameters == true && (j - start) % ull_int((stop - start) * n / 4) == 0 && j > 0) { 
        out << n << "-th quarter of " << _id << endl; 
        n++; 
    }
}
```

}
, here is the caulculate_spinelements function:

```
std::tuple<int, int, int> calculateSpinElements(int L, ull_int& j) {
int bSz = 0; //bosonic total spin - spin of upper orbital locked to n=1 filling
int fSz = 0; //fermionic total spin
int N_e = 0; // numer of electrons in given state
std::vector<int> temp = int_to_binary(j, L);

for (int k = 0; k < L; k++) {
    if (temp[k] < 4) bSz += 1;
    else bSz -= 1;
    if (temp[k] % 4 == 1) {
        fSz += 1;
        N_e += 1;
    }
    else if (temp[k] % 4 == 2) {
        fSz -= 1;
        N_e += 1;
    }
    else if (temp[k] % 4 == 3)
        N_e += 2;
}

return std::make_tuple(bSz, fSz, N_e);
```

}

and her is the separation to threads:

```
void HamiltonianKH::generate_mapping() {
ull_int start = 0, stop = std::pow(8, L);
//mapping_kernel(start, stop, mapping, L, Sz, num_of_electrons);
//Threaded
std::vector<std::vector<ull_int>*> map_threaded(num_of_threads);
std::vector<std::thread> threads;
threads.reserve(num_of_threads);
for (int t = 0; t < num_of_threads; t++) {
    start = t * (ull_int)std::pow(8, L) / num_of_threads;
    stop = ((t + 1) == num_of_threads ? (ull_int)std::pow(8, L) : (ull_int)std::pow(8, L) * (t + 1) / num_of_threads);
    map_threaded[t] = new std::vector<ull_int>();
    threads.emplace_back(&HamiltonianKH::mapping_kernel, this, start, stop, map_threaded[t], t);
}
for (auto& t : threads) t.join();
for (auto& t : threads) t.~thread();

ull_int size = 0;
for (auto& t : map_threaded) {
    size += t->size();
}

out << "size = " << size << endl;
for (auto & t : map_threaded)
    mapping->insert(mapping->end(), t->begin(), t->end());
//sort(mapping->begin(), mapping->end());
if (show_system_size_parameters == true) {
    out << "Mapping generated with  " << mapping->size() << "  elements" << endl;
    out << "Last element = " << mapping->at(mapping->size() - 1) << endl;
}
//out << mapping[0] << " " << mapping[mapping.size() - 1] << endl;
assert(mapping->size() > 0 && "Not possible number of electrons - no. of states < 1");
```

}

The variables: mapping, L, num_of_electrons and Sz are public fields in the object. The whole code has over 2000 lines, but the execution after the generate_mapping() call is irrelevant to the problem.

Do any of you guys have an idea, why this piece of code executes longer on more threads?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Memory allocation is synchronized, so all those `push_back`s cost you.

Comment: You should absolutely not explicitly destroy your threads. They will be destroyed by the vector that owns them.

Comment: Yes, but single thread and multihread  calls push_back the same number of times, so I don't think that push_back is slowing this code down so heavily:

Comment: single thread: 12 sec execution
8 threads: 50 sec execution

Comment: "Yes, but single thread and multihread calls push_back the same number of times, so I don't think that push_back is slowing this code down so heavily" -- Locking a mutex in an individual processor's Level 1 Cache is a lot faster than locking a mutex in the shared Level 3 Cache.

Comment: "Locking a mutex in an individual processor's Level 1 Cache is a lot faster than locking a mutex in the shared Level 3 Cache" 
-- I'm not that familiar with how the processor itself operates with memory, but each thread ha it's own vector to push_back elements, so here shouldn't be any shared mutex locked, ate least not associated with the push_back itself. The only shared elements among threads are the integers, L, Sz, num_of_threads and the makro show_system_size_parameters

Comment: All containers draw their allocations from the same memory heap, and need to cooperate (by locking shared structures) in order to do so. The many, many `temp` vectors you create will each need to wait their turn before allocating from the shared heap.

Comment: "All containers draw their allocations from the same memory heap, and need to cooperate (by locking shared structures) in order to do so. The many, many temp vectors you create will each need to wait their turn before allocating from the shared heap" -- would it be better to create 1 temp vector per thread, which will be then overwritten by the int_to_binary command in every iteration?

Comment: Yes, as long as int_to_binary is rewritten to modify the array in-place rather than returning it. That will reduce allocation contention, as well as being more cache-coherent.

Comment: "Yes, as long as int_to_binary is rewritten to modify the array in-place rather than returning it. That will reduce allocation contention, as well as being more cache-coherent. "  --  Thank you very much @Sneftel, even the performance on single thread increased at least 2 times. This does solve my problem!!